Should I be able to run a half Marathon in Zone 4?
On Monday I finally managed to run a half Marathon in under two hours (1:55:31), here is the pace and heart rate data from Strava:

The curious thing is that I managed to run pretty much the whole thing towards the top end of zone 4.  I have calculated my HR zones using the heart rate reserve method, with a max heart rate of 175 (which I have estimated as the max heart rate I have seen from "race pace" 5k runs and maximal effort Cooper tests), which gives a zone 4 of 147-160 bpm, my resting heart rate is low forties.  My average heart rate during the run was 156 bpm, which is 89% of my maximum heart rate - the upper end of zone 4.
I have read that I shouldn't be able to run in zone 4 for more than 30-40 minutes due to lactic acid build up.  However, I managed the run without feeling unduly uncomfortable - I was breathing hard, but never got out of breath, my legs were tired after about 12km, but as you can see I held the pace pretty steady and still had something left in the tank to pick up the pace for the last 2km.
So my questions are: (i) is it O.K. for me to run with such a high heart rate for so long?  (ii) does it imply my heart rate zones are wrong? (iii) does this tell me anything useful about my lactate threshold and does it have any implications for my training?
Possibly relevant info: The run was on a running track, I am in my mid-fifties, been running for a bit less than two years, 6'2", 82kg, had toast and a coffee before the run, fueled run by eating a jelly baby after each km after 5km (celebrated the PR by eating the rest of the packet afterwards ;o).


I have read that I shouldn't be able to run in zone 4 for more than 30-40 minutes due to lactic acid build up. However, I managed the run without feeling unduly uncomfortable

This is correct, and the only plausible explanation is that you weren't actually in zone 4.

So my questions are:
(i) is it O.K. for me to run with such a high heart rate for so long?

Yes.

(ii) does it imply my heart rate zones are wrong?

Yes. More specifically, you must have been in a lower zone than zone 4, so your zone 3/4 transition point must occur at a higher heart rate than what the heart rate reserve method predicted for you.

(iii) does this tell me anything useful about my lactate threshold and does it have any implications for my training?

Only that your LT2 threshold occurs at a heart rate higher than ~160 BPM. So if you were specifically trying to do zone 4 training, you'd want to do it at a faster pace than your half-marathon pace, aiming to reach a higher heart rate, and to experience the inability to maintain that output for longer than maybe 10-20 minute bouts.

Thanks, that is a very helpful answer!  It suggests my zone 4 and zone 5 are both crammed in to 160-175 bpm, which is a pretty narrow range.  I guess I'll have to get a lab test at some point to sort out my HR zones properly.  It was one of the rare occasions when I was trying to run to a pace (5:40/km to get below 2 hours) rather than to HR.  My intentional zone 4 runs are 10k at about 5:00/km (with only a slightly higher average HR) but definitely more than 20 mins, so perhaps they are not really zone 4 either.
